# Apache starts even if web sharing is disabled

Tags: macos, preferences, apache, services

I do web development so I normally have web sharing turned on in the sharing preferences.

After upgrading to Lion I have been continuing with the web development projects I have pretty much as normal.  However, I noticed something weird today.  I'm not doing development at the moment so I thought I could save some system resources by going into the preferences and turning web sharing off for now.  However when I did, I found that web sharing was already unchecked!  Sure enough, I could access web pages and scripts on localhost.  I turned web sharing on and off again and localhost files could no longer be accessed, as expected.

I tried restarting the machine to see what effect that would have, and sure enough, Apache started up and was running when I got to the desktop even though web sharing was disabled.  Enabling and disabling it again shut the server down.

So a few questions occur:

1. Why is Apache running if web sharing is turned off?
2. Is this something I need to worry about and/or fix?
3. If this is something that needs to be fixed, then how?
4. Are there any other services that Lion starts up that it doesn't tell the user about?

Comment: Are you sure didn't install a second parallel installation of Apache? I'm thinking of Mamp, or through Macports perhaps?

Comment: nope. It's purely Apple's Apache, with the Liip PHP build

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was? Or is it still a problem?